# Home button brings back to my app

Tags: java, android

I am making a car launcher application, which contains shortcuts to other apps, when i'm in another app i'd like to press the home button and go back to my launcher
So basically i need to override the home button outside of my app,the override has to work only when my app is opened in the background so when i close my app the home button will work as usual taking you to your default launcher

Can i implement something like this or i'm asking too much?

Answer (score 12):

There is no way to intercept the home button on Android, unless you make your app the home screen. This is for security reasons, so that malicious apps cannot take over your device by overriding all the buttons that can exit. The home button is the one sure shot way to be able to leave any app.

In short, no it's not possible, and even if it were, it is a serious disruption in what a user expects out of an app's behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you go the route of making your app act be a replacement home screen you'll have to include in the install instructions for the users to set your app as the default launcher.

Then the home button would take them to your app. In order to get it to switch back to the default launcher when they are not in "car" mode would be a bit tricky but you could prolly achieve it with some sort of fork activity that checks if car mode is enabled if so go to your car mode launcher if not go to the default launcher (it gets trickier if the user already has a different 3rd party launcher) So essentially your app will always be the home screen app no matter if car mode is enabled or not, but if it is not then you manually start the "normal" home screen.

Comment: However, this would prompt the user to select the home screen to go to everytime they press the homebutton in a scenario outside your use case.

Comment: @RaghavSood I'm not sure what you mean. It would prompt them every time if they never checked the "Use this as default" box that is in the pop-up yes. But otherwise there would never be any prompts, it would always go to either OP's created "car mode home" or the default home. Presumeably there would be some sort of widget or shortcut or notification or something that would allow the user to quickly/easily transition into and out of the car mode.

Comment: I meant in the case that the user has a different main launcher than the OP's app. In such a case, both launchers would be available. If only the OP's launcher is used, then no problem.

Comment: ahh I see. and I agree if they were already using a different one it'd be a bit trickier. I think though somehow you could figure out the package/activity name of the 3rd party launcher that they are using and manually start that instead of the default launcher built into the system. Though I don't know exactly how to get that info, but I think the system will share it with you some how.

Comment: Yeah. You should be able to get that. The system settings app's source code should have it.

Comment: Nice idea, basically a launcher chooser based on a condition, but i think this would alter too much how android works.
i think i'll leave my launcher as a normal app, maybe i'll make it persistent so the system won't kill it, then the user would need only to press back to get back to my application